# Can't start mining with geth

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum, mining, ether

there is a problem with ether mining. I want to start mining via geth with the
`geth --mine --miner.etherbase=<my wallet>`
command, but I get a error:

```
panic: ethash (pow) sealing not supported any more

goroutine 4247 [running]:
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/consensus/ethash.(*Ethash).Seal(0xc00055a2e0?, {0x41b566?, 0xc000764000?}, 0xc000764108?, 0xc000764000?, 0xa94f5f96355d5204?)
    github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/consensus/ethash/ethash.go:84 +0x27
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/consensus/beacon.(*Beacon).Seal(0xc0000b3580, {0x2069660, 0xc000580800}, 0xc0005c35e0, 0x11736706ba90f23b?, 0xfaf244ff7701e301?)
    github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/consensus/beacon/consensus.go:387 +0x9e
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/miner.(*worker).taskLoop(0xc000244280)
    github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/miner/worker.go:706 +0x2fc
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/miner.newWorker
    github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/miner/worker.go:329 +0xa8d
```

. The documentation says

```
Proof-of-work mining is no longer used to secure Ethereum Mainnet. The information below is included because the Ethash code is still part of Geth and it could be used to create a private proof-of-work network or testnet.
```

but how to start mining without Pow?